# Deployed ROR API to Heroku and broke it

Tags: ios, heroku, rails-api

I'm working on a Rails API for an iOS app. I was able to run it on my localhost and consume it from the iPhone simulator but now I want to test on the device. I successfully pushed to heroku and changed my ROOT_URL to be the one that it provided. Now when I visit the application URL (http://sleepy-lake-5504.herokuapp.com/v1/users if you really wanted to know), I get the error message:

---

Application Error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

---

instead of JSON data.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to do something special with heroku to hit it as an API?
Needless to say it's making me very sad.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @VigneshPT that worked but is a temporary fix im afraid. At least I can put off debugging deployment and keep working :) Thanks a bunch

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, are you sure that your deployment is set-up properly.

Comment: No. It's something with unicorn.rb - I just really don't feel like dealing with it at this point haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a tunnel to your localhost using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Ngrok will forward your localhost and give you a URL which you can use in your iPhone.
This will help you to debug your localhost without actually hosting your site so that you get a better idea of whats going wrong. Let me know if that helps.